# openshift-origin ansible install origin 1.4

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I'm using this ansible script https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible (with master branch or release-1.4). And I want to install openshift-origin 1.4, but by default, the ansible installs a 1.3 version(oc version).

I'm wondering is there any special config in ansible hosts that I need to install 1.4 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using these attributes:

```
deployment_type=origin
containerized=true
openshift_release=v1.4
openshift_image_tag=v1.4.0
```

- OpenShift Origin v1.4 on CentOS 7.x: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OOnGK-XeVY
- Ref inventory file: https://github.com/gshipley/installcentos/blob/master/inventory.erb

Comment: looks like for now, only containerized is supported for 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [byo config](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/blob/master/inventory/byo/hosts.origin.example) for helpful examples. Specifically you're looking to add/change the following line in your Ansible hosts file:

```
openshift_release=v1.4
```

As someone who went through this installation yesterday, there are a few issues with deploying. Most notably: make sure you have Ansible version 2.2.0.0 installed. Version 2.2.1.0 causes an obscure issue when deploying. Additionally, make sure you checkout the release-1.4 branch of the openshift-ansible repo instead of master.

Comment: Thanks. I set openshift_release=v1.4 in ansible hosts, but the installation failed. 

FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Detected OpenShift version 1.3.1 does not match requested openshift_release 1.4. You may need to adjust your yum repositories, inventory, or run the appropriate OpenShift upgrade playbook."}

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference if you tried 
`git checkout tag/{openshift_ansible_version}`

Look for the specific tag and you can check it out easily